# MySQL Query Complex Relationship of One Way Linking

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I've been pondering over this for a while.  Basically I have a list of websites in a table.  Each one of these websites has several posts.  Each post can link to at least one other website.  I keep a record of what links where.  I need to generate a query that gives me a list of all websites that a certain post COULD link to.  There are, however, some rules to this:

- Each post can link to multiple websites
- Each post can only link to websites that do not have a post linking back to it
- Each post can link to the same website multiple times (so if it's been linked in the past, that's fine)
- A website can link to it's own posts

Take below, a representation of my websites, each has a number of posts.
http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/815/emptyd.jpg

Now, if I add all of A's possible links:
http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/4931/alinks.jpg

But now, no other site is able to link back to A, because A is linking to them (rule 2).  See below to what C can link to:
http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/273/clinks.jpg

So, now anything that A or C links to can't link back to it, this lowers the options for each of the other sites.  It's important to remember that not every website will link to all possible combinations, I just need these combinations returning from the query.  If you look below I've added links from G and D, these aren't every possible link that they produce, just some that are possible:
[D and G linking http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/7140/dglinks.jpg](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/7140/dglinks.jpg)

It's starting to take shape now.  You'll notice that a lot of websites now link to H, so H's linking options are very limited.  In fact it can only ever link to F, B, E and itself (rule 4).

I'm not being lazy here and just asking your to write a query for me.  I've spent a long time trying to work this out and not sure where to start.

Here's a link to some sample data and to the table structure: http://pastie.org/1506715

I have been able to produce something close to all outcomes by using a cross join:

```
SELECT t1.* , t2.* 
FROM test_posts t1, test_posts as t2
WHERE
t1.post_id != t2.post_id
ORDER BY
t1.post_id, t2.post_id;
```

I feel like it's quite close, but I'm just not there.  I think I need to use a NOT EXISTS clause with a subquery, but I'm unsure as to exactly what it is I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent about an hour on this and I can tell you one thing, this was difficult. I tried many different ways to get the answer and what I came up with doesn't seem to be too efficient but yet the only way.

You are looking for a difference, which means I select all the possible combinations where a combination is not yet set. This seems weird to say, but that is what's happening.

```
SELECT post.post_id, website.website_id
FROM test_posts post
  JOIN test_posts website ON website.website_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT sl.website_id
  FROM test_posts f
    INNER JOIN test_smartlink_to_websites sl ON f.post_id = sl.post_id
  WHERE f.post_id = post.post_id
)
ORDER BY post_id
```

Comment: I did test it against your provided data, and I made sure it got the right result.

Comment: Seems to work on the test data and my live data.  I'll implement it and see how it goes.  Seriously, thanks so much for taking the time to look at it - bit of a strange one because it feels like it should be so easy, yet it really isn't.

Comment: Ya I thought it would some simple join, but after playing with it I realized I couldn't. I'm not a professional at SQL, but because you need a NOT IN then that's what I came up with.